# terraform resource force creation

Tags: terraform, infrastructure-as-code

I would like to know if there is a way to always create a new terraform resource and not destroy any previously deployed resource.

example
resource group 1 deployment

```
provider "azurerm" {
version = "=2.20.0"
features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
name     = "rg-example-resources-1"
}
```

say now I want to deploy rg-example-resources-2 but I don't want to duplicate the resource block. I'm aware of *count* but I don't want to use it. if I change the resource group name terraform understand it as a replacement :(

any clue ?

Comment: How would that be declarative? Terraform is a declarative language. It sounds like you want an imperative command here?

Comment: it would be declarative if the input are being read from an external file

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why do you need this, but you can use terraform workspace for this (current workspace is 'default'):
'terraform workspace new bar'
'terraform apply'

New resource will be created in the new workspace.
To use it without errors, you need to change resource group name, e.g.:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "rg-example-resources-${terraform.workspace}"
}
```

See the details here - https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html

As an option, you can use counter block.
If you don't want to re-create first resource group, you can generate the same resource group with count block:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "rg-example-resources-${count.index + 1}"
}
```